# datetime for columns with no date names

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a file with the following column names:

```
STOD_WMO        TIMI    AR      MAN     DAGUR   KLST        
MINUTA  MINSL   SEKSL   H_M     PS      T       RH         
TD      H_FT    D       F_KT    LAT     LONG    FJARL   
STIGHR
```

I want to read this data and then transform the columns which represent Year(AR),Month(called MAN), Day( called DAGUR),minute (MINUTA) in a format of year:day:hour:minute :
I'm doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/nfs/potts.jasmin-north/scratch/earic    
/radiosonde_Iceland_analysis
/data/keflavik_radiosonde_1991-2005',sep = "\s+|\t+|
\s+\t+|\t+\s+")


## transform the time colmns in 1 column 
df['date'] =   
pd.to_datetime(df[['AR','MAN','DAGUR','KLST','MINUTA']])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year,    
month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

How can I have python recognize the names I m using as Year, Hour etc and do what I want ( change the data format) ? 
Thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to rename your cols. Can you also share a small dataset? 2 rows?

Comment: Hi - thanks a lot, I actually managed to solve the problem since then.

Comment: Great!! Post your answer and accept it. Helps the community!